# re-plot existing figures in a new supblot in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

Say in the process of visualizing data, I later decided to combine two existing plots which are heavily annotated in a subplot to compare them side by side on the same window.

yes, I could go back and recreate these in a subplot in the first place.  But, is there a way I could grab the axes or the figure handles -- I don't understand how it all works---whatever captures all the content of the individual figures and use data that to create the new subplots?

something along the lines of

```
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

x=list(range(1,11))
seed(1)
y1= randint(5, 35, 10)
seed(2)
y2= randint(5, 35, 10)
seed(3)
y3=randint(5, 35, 10)

fig1=plt.figure(1)
ax1=plt.plot(x,y1,x,y2,x,y3)
plt.xlabel('Xaxis')
plt.ylabel('yaxis')
plt.title('Some Plot')
plt.text(10,10, 'some text')

fig2=plt.figure(2)
ax2= plt.plot(x,y1+y2+y3)

# later, I say decided I wanted to also display the two plots as subplots in the same window.
fig3=pltfigure(3)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(ax1) # plt.plot(fig1.lines),plt.plot(fig1)
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(ax2)
```

I'm looking for a simple way to grab all the content already plotted in figures 1 and 2 and passing it directly to the subplots on figure 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `ax1` and `ax2` in your code is a list of `Line2D`. You can extract the lines' data with `.get_data()` and plot:

```
# later, I say decided I wanted to also display the two plots as subplots in the same window.
fig3=plt.figure(3)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
for line in ax1:
    plt.plot(*line.get_data())
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
for line in ax1:
    plt.plot(*line.get_data())
```

Output:

[image]